# How to develop ue4 plugins to simulate the viewpoint in unity 3D?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

**Unity 3d** has two **viewpoints**, one is `game` and another is`scene`. when you move objects in `scene` you can see changes happened in `game` in the same time. while the reverse is true. But **UE4** doesn't have this function. So I wonder if I can develop a **plugin** for **UE4** to achieve that? does anyone have a clue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkaPO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unreal 4: Go to Window -> Viewport 2. Drag the window somewhere and you will have 2 viewports:

[image]

Press play, only one viewport will display the "gameview" and the other remains as "sceneview" - Moving stuff in the 2nd Viewport will not update the game!
But I found this plugin:
https://github.com/jackknobel/GameViewportSync

You can see if that works for you or use it as a reference to get started developing your own plugin.